# How to get a colon after (year) instead of "." in References. Can't manage it for @misc

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to get a colon after (year). This: `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}` works, but not for `@misc` entries in my bib file. I have tried everything, but this dot after (year) for `@misc` is persistent. I hope somebody can help me in this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=10, sortcites = true, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}, urlseen = { letzte \"Uberpr\"ufung am}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1,\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{Issue #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{\textit{#1},}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{{\textit{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\begin{document}
    \title{ICOs}
    \author{Constantin Budin}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \input{Einleitung.tex}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my .bib:

```
@article{NowWit,
    author = "Nowiński, Witold and Kozma, Miklós",
    title = "How Can Blockchain Technology Disrupt the Existing Business Models?",
    journal = "Entrepreneurial Business and Economics Review",
    year = "2017",
    pages = "173--188",
    volume = "5",
    number = "3",
}

@misc{DeloitteBlock,
    author = "Deloitte",
    year = "2016",
    url = "https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/ch/Documents/innovation/ch-en-innovation-deloitte-what-is-blockchain-2016.pdf",
    urldate = "2017-12-26",
    entrysubtype = "inet"
}
```

The offender:

[image: the offender]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why are using `german` instead of `ngerman` as babel language option?

Comment: I think the entry of type `@misc` is missing the field `title  = "What is a blockchain?",`. I really don't think it's appropriate to substitute the item's URL for the title. A side-effect of providing a `title` field is that the colon-after-year issue disappears automatically.

Comment: Another general comment: The instruction `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{{\textit{#1}}}` almost certainly guarantees exceedingly bad line breaks in some URL strings associated with entries of type `@misc`. It's better to load the `url` package -- preferably with the options `spaces`, `obeyspaces`, and `hyphens` -- and to issue the instruction `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{{\def\UrlFont{\itshape}\url{#1}}}`. That way, LaTeX will find many more permissible line breaks, while  still typesetting the URL in italic mode, greatly reducing the odds of massively-overfull lines.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}` is the right code for this. But because you are missing the `title` you don't get to see the colon. This is essentially https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/554. At the moment I know of no good way around this.

Comment: There are more elegant methods to change the format of `volume` and `number` than `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1,\space}\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{Issue #1}`. Ideally `\DeclareFieldFormat` should not contain trailing punctuation, and strings should be localised with `\bibstring`.  As Mico mentioned `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{{\textit{#1}}}` is  not ideal since URLs won't be treated as such any more. `sorting=nty` is unusual in combination with `style=authoryear`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

Is the correct code to obtain a colon after the year. With newer versions of `biblatex` I would suggest

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

instead, but both versions do the same thing.

The problem here is not that you have a `@misc` entry, the problem is that you have a sparsely populated entry.

To understand what is going on here we need to understand the concept of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. See §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

The gist of it is that `biblatex` does not print punctuation (in a `\setunit`) directly. Instead punctuation is added to the punctuation buffer. The contents of the buffer are then printed only when the next text is printed by `biblatex`. This avoids spurious double punctuation if a field is missing. The punctuation buffer is overwritten by subsequent calls to `\setunit`. So after `\setunit{\addcomma\space}\setunit{\addperiod\space}` the punctuation buffer will contain `\addperiod\space`. Most punctuation is set in `\setunit`. There is also `\printunit` that command adds punctuation to the buffer that cannot be overwritten later on, so `\printunit{\addcomma\space}\setunit{\addperiod\space}` will leave `\addcomma\space` in the punctuation buffer.

A bibdriver will roughly contain the following sequence of commands to print author and  title.

```
\usebibmacro{author}%
\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
\usebibmacro{title}%
\newunit
```

In your example `DeloitteBlock` does not have a title. So here is what happens. The author is printed (along with the year), then `\printdelim{nametitledelim}` is added to the punctuation buffer. Then `biblatex` tries to print the title, but there is nothing to do, so nothing is printed, in particular the punctuation buffer is left as is and not printed. Then `\newunit`, which amongst other things does `\setunit{\newunitpunct}`, overwrites the punctuation buffer: it now contains `\newunitpunct`, the `\printdelim{nametitledelim}` is gone.

So it is a known issue that appears in sparsely populated entries if different punctuation is to be used. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/554

The easy way out is to provide `DeloitteBlock` with a title. Almost all entries should have a title, it should in most cases be easy to determine. `What is a blockchain?` seems to work in this case.

The more complicated technical solution is to set `\printdelim{nametitledelim}` with `\printunit` so that the punctuation buffer cannot be overwritten.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
    {\printunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
    {}{}}
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother
```

This can have unwanted knock-on effects for other punctuation later on in sparsely populated entries.