# What do \setunit and \newunit do?

Tags: macros, biblatex

I'm learning how to customize BibLaTeX styles at the moment. When digging through the `*.bbx` files I often encounter the commands `\setunit{...}` and `\newunit`. The most common use of `\setunit{...}`seems to be `\setunit{\addspace}`, but there are many other applications as well. Sometimes also the starred version `\setunit*{...}` is used. `\newunit` seemingly takes no arguments and has no starred version.

Many bibliography macros I'm modyfing use these commands so I'd really like to understand what their effect is. I wasn't able to find any information about them (neither on this site nor in the BibLaTeX documentation nor via web search). As they always appear together and also because of the similar names I'm guessing there is some connection between the two, so I'm asking both in one question.

Comment: Section "4.7 Punctuation and Spacing" of biblatex's documentation does provide explanation about them. Did you have a look at it?

Comment: @gusbrs Ah you're right. I was using the German translation of the documentation which is obviously missing the entire chapter 4. Thanks! (Probably I should delete the question now?)

Comment: You will also want to read §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker*, a very short version of what biblatex's punctuation tracker does can be found in my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408007/35864. For all intents and purposes `\newunit` is the same as `\setunit{\newunitpunct}`, so you will only need to understand `\setunit`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant sections of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) are §4.7 *Punctuation and Spacing* and §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker*.

Thanks to the punctuation tracker you do not have to worry about double punctuation, spurious spaces or missing fields.

To use the punctuation tracker you have to use `\setunit`. Instead of writing the punctuation command directly as in

```
\printfield{title}%
\addcomma\space
\printfield{edition}%
\addcomma\space
\printfield{note}%
```

we write

```
\printfield{title}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{edition}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{note}%
```

In the first case `biblatex` would immediately print a comma and space after the title and the edition. But if no edition is present we would be left with

> Title, , note

Using `\setunit` and the punctuation tracker, however, we get

> Title, note

That is because `\setunit` does not actually print its argument. Instead it places its argument in a buffer. The buffer is printed as soon as a `\printtext`, `\printfield`, `\print...` command following it prints something. In the example above the first `\setunit` sends its argument off to the buffer, `\printfield{edition}` does nothing, the second `\setunit` sends its argument off replacing the earlier value. Then `\prinfield{note}` prints something and `biblatex` inserts the punctuation buffer right before it prints the contents of the `note` field. This is what the `biblatex` documentation refers to as asynchronous treatment of text/`\print...` (which is written immediately) and punctuation (which is only printed when necessary).

Because the buffer is overwritten by subsequent `\setunit`s, both

```
\printfield{title}%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printfield{edition}%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printfield{note}%
```

and

```
\printfield{title}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{edition}%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printfield{note}%
```

give

> Title. Note

if the `edition` field is empty.

There is also `\setunit*` that only inserts its argument into the buffer if the last `\print...` command before it printed something. So

```
\printfield{title}%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printfield{edition}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{note}%
```

gives

> Title. Note

if the edition is missing and

> Title. Edition, note

if that is not the case.

Since the punctuation tracker only 'sees' text printed via `\print...` commands. You should not write hard-coded text directly into a bibmacro, it should always go into a `\printtext`. This is different for `\DeclareFieldFormat`, hard coded text is OK there, `\printtext` within `\DeclareFieldFormat` could even confuse the tracker.

`\newunit` is for all intents and purposes the same as `\setunit{\newunitpunct}`. In fact I was surprised that internally it is not defined like that; the actual definition is on a much lower level.
So `\newunit` does not need an argument.
`\newunit` is used as the 'standard' way to separate `\print...` commands, `\setunit` is only used for occasions where `\newunitpunct` does not apply (of which there are many).

`\newblock` is similar to `\newunit`, but it has no equivalent to `\setunit`, i.e. no `\setblock` or similar. It marks the start of a new block. Blocks are larger than the units marked by `\newunit`. A start of a new block inserts `\newblockpunct` after the punctuation mark inserted by the punctuation buffer.

Comment: moewe, I know it is not literally in the OP, but I leave a request for a comment on `\newblock` too, as it is usually used in conjunction and interacts with `\newunit`.