# Bibtex remove dot between "Title" and "Journal"

Tags: biblatex

I do have an issue with my references and would like to remove the dot "." between the title and journal name when printing the references. Can anyone help? Here is my current code:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
    \renewbibmacro{in:}{\newline}
    \renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{%
    \bibsentence#1}
    \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

for the `.bib` entry:

```
@article{Adams.2007,
 author = {{Adams RH, Alitalo K}},
 year = {2007},
 title = {Molecular regulation of angiogenesis and lymphangiogenesis},
 pages = {464--478},
 volume = {8},
 number = {6},
 journal = {Nat Rev Mol Cell Biol}
}
```

which gives me the following output:

[image: Article output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bare punctuation/spacing command such as `\newunit` in a bibmacro throws off `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. Punctuation and spacing commands should always be wrapped in `\setunit`/`\printunit` if they appear in bibmacros or drivers; they can only appear without those wrappers in field formats.

Instead of

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\newline}
```

you need something like

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\printunit{\newunitpunct\newline}}
```

That way `\newunitpunct\newline` is added to the punctuation buffer and only printed when it is needed. You can read more about the punctuation tracker in [What do \setunit and \newunit do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864) and section §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* (pp. 312-317 in v3.14) of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Note that `author = {{Adams RH, Alitalo K}},` is wrong. Several names must always be separated with an `and` and should be given in `Family, Given` or `Given Family` format regardless of the desired output (see [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) and [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864)). The output can be controlled by the style (see the MWE below: you need the `terseinits` option and a few other things).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric,
  giveninits, terseinits]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\printunit{\newunitpunct\newline}}

\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence#1}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{adams,
  author  = {Adams, R. H. and Alitalo, K.},
  title   = {Molecular Regulation of Angiogenesis and Lymphangiogenesis},
  journal = {Nat Rev Mol Cell Biol},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {6},
  year    = {2007},
  pages   = {464--478},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,adams}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Adams RH, Alitalo K. ‘Molecular Regulation of Angiogenesis and Lymphangiogenesis’.//Nat Rev Mol Cell Biol 8.6 (2007), pp. 464–478]

Comment: \renewbibmacro{in:}{\printunit{\newunitpunct\newline}} is working, thank you very much!

Comment: @Jonas If the answer works for you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark on the top left of the answer, so the question is marked as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers