# Display DOI in DeclareCiteCommand

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, doi

I would like to display `DOI` with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. I'm using `\documentclass{report}`.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}




\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}%
{
    \usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace
}%
{%
    \mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
    \addcomma\addspace by \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
    \addcomma\addspace \thefield{year}%
    \addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}}%
    \addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}}%
    \mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}%
    \addcomma\addspace%
}
{}
{
    \usebibmacro{postnote}%
    \addspace%
    \mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}%
    \adddot%
}


\begin{document}


\mycite{sampleentry}




\end{document}
```

In the bibliography, I put this entry found in "Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association, Seventh Edition (2020)":

```
@article{sampleentry,
    author      =   {Wang, Xiaoye and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey},
    year        =   {2018},
    month       =   {06},
    pages       =   {1513},
    title       =   {Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception},
    volume      =   {44},
    number      =   {10},
    journal     =   {Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance},
    doi         =   {https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553},
}
```

However, I only get `\thefield{doi}`. Is there another command to print the `DOI`?

Comment: Please note that it is extremely bad style to have `\addcomma\addspace` without a surrounding `\setunit` in bibmacros, drivers or citation definitions. `\thefield` should almost never be used for printing. If you want to print fields use `\printfield`. Formatting commands should not be added manually around `\printfield` (or `\thefield` for that matter), they should be added in field format definitions.

Comment: Why is it bad practice?

Comment: Because "naked" punctuation (outside of `\setunit`/the punctuation buffer) is liable to produce clashing/double punctuation if fields are missing. `biblatex` has some emergency measures to prevent this (which is why in your examples the issue will probably not arise). The punctuation buffer provides a predictable framework to deal with punctuation that does not require TeX magic to avoid punctuation clashes. ...

Comment: ...  Similarly applying formatting outside of `\printunit` (or even worse `\thefield`) will usually yield bad results for missing fields (try `\mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}` on something with a missing `number` field).

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to use `\thefield` for printing. Instead use `\printfield` and friends or even better pre-defined bibmacros that print whole chunks of the data you want to show. You should also not have bare `\addcomma\addspace`s flying around. Those should be inside `\setunit`s to make use of `biblatex`'s punctuation buffer.

As shown the macro also risks introducing massive amount of undesirable space.

I suggest the following approach, where `\printfield{doi}` to print the DOI works perfectly fine.

Logically, however, it is a bit unusual and possibly risky to print entry data in the "postnote" code: If you cite multiple entries you end up with the data from the last key. The others are ignored. It might be more logical to move all printing into the loopcode and possibly warn if more than one entry is cited.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{ccdoi}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}
      {\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\CustomCite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{title}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \bibstring{byauthor}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printnames[default]{author}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \printdate
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printfield[ccdoi]{doi}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\CustomCite{sigfridsson}

\CustomCite[381]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, by Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde, 1998, Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P)]

---

The problem in the updated code was

```
\url{\thefield{doi}}
```

Depending on the definition `\url` reads and prints its argument almost verbatim. In this case this means that the output that it produces is `\thefield{doi}`, which is not what you want. (`\mkbibparens{\thefield{doi}}` instead of `\mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}` would have produced output more to your liking. But you would have gotten into trouble with hyphenation and linking, so this is definitely not recommended.) Again, you want to use `\printfield{doi}` instead, because that uses `\url` (and friends) in the correct way.

Comment: How can I know where the error came from? ``to make use of biblatex's punctuation buffer.`` What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dunno The punctuation buffer helps you deal with punctuation in case of missing fields. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864 for an introduction to the concept.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that no command can be used in the `postnote` part.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\CustomCite}
{
    \usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace
}
{%
    \mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
    \addcomma\addspace by \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author} %
    \addcomma\addspace \thefield{year} %
    \addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}} %
    \addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}} %
    \mkbibparens{\thefield{number}} %
    \addcomma \addspace %
    \mkbibparens{\thefield{doi}} %
}
{}
{
    \usebibmacro{postnote} %
    \adddot %
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the case. If I take the code from the question and embed it into a working document I get the output I (and I guess also you) expected. Please post a useful example document that shows how things go wrong.

Comment: Why should I provide something else since I solved my own problem? I wouldn't have come here in the first place on a Sunday. Anyway I edited my post.