# Add prenote argument in DeclareCiteCommand

Tags: biblatex, biber, declarecitecommand

I would like to edit a custom cite command to check whether or not a prenote is specified.

At the moment, it looks like this:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\MyCommand}
{
    \usebibmacro{prenote} %
}
{
    some stuff %
}
{}
{
    \usebibmacro{postnote} %
    \adddot %
}
```

Is it possible to check the presence of an argument and change the precode accordingly? Like print `A` if there is no argument and `B` if an argument is specified.

I have a second problem related to this: when I use \MyCommand[argument]{resource}, the argument gets printed at the end of the command just before the dot, as a postnote. Is there a way to force LaTeX to consider that a single argument should be considered as a prenote and thus printed at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `\DeclareCiteCommand` and friends the prenote and postnote arguments can be accessed as if they were fields from the `.bib` file. So you can test for the presence or absence of `prenote` with `\iffieldundef`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareFieldFormat{red}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\MyCommand}
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {\printtext[red]{replacement for prenote}%
      \setunit{\prenotedelim}}
     {\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\printtext{something here}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\MyCommand{sigfridsson}

\MyCommand[post]{sigfridsson}

\MyCommand[pre][post]{sigfridsson}

\MyCommand[pre][]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: replacement for prenote something here replacement for prenote something here, post pre something here, post pre something here]

Comment: Thank you. Why do you use ``setunit``? Is there a way to consider a single argument as prenote?

Comment: @Dunno With `\setunit` we make use of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker, which means that undesirable double punctuation and punctuation clashes are avoided. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864.

Comment: It's not easily possible to have `biblatex` treat a single argument as `prenote` (without messing with the internal implementation of the cite commands, at least). A single argument is considered a `postnote`. But you can test if there is a postnote and no prenote and just pretend it is a prenote in that case. If you need help with that open a new question (preferably with a usable example document and a precise description of what you want to achieve).